# How to accept time from the user and store them into an array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, time

I want to accept (say)3 time elements (for example 8:30, 8:20 & 8:00) from user and store it in an array using 'datenum'. How can i achieve that? Please help.

Comment: Are you having a code specific issue?

Comment: @Idris: All i wanna know is that, just like we accept simple integers into array using 'input' function, I wanna accept time elements from user and store it in an array.

Comment: @Vakh: I know that i can store time elements in a variable using 'datenum'. But i dont know how to store time elements through user prompts.

Comment: @rayryeng: Il give it a try. Hope it works.

Comment: I'll write an example for you.  Give me a moment

Comment: @Necromancer - Done.  Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to prompt the user given the **current** day and year and you **only** want the current time (hours and minutes - seconds is 0), you can do the following:

```
dateNumArray = []; %// Store datenums here

%// Enter a blank line to quit this loop
while true
    timestr = input('Enter a time: ', 's');
    if (isempty(timestr))
        break;
    end
    %// Split the string up at the ':'
    %//splitStr = strsplit(timestr, ':'); %// For MATLAB R2012 and up
    splitStr = regexp(timestr, ':', 'split');

    %// Read in the current date as a vector
    %// Format of: [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second]
    timeRead = clock;
    %// Replace hours and minutes with user prompt
    %// Zero the seconds
    timeRead(4:6) = [str2num(splitStr{1}) str2num(splitStr{2}) 0];

    %// Convert to datenum format
    dateNumArray = [dateNumArray datenum(timeRead)];
 end
```

What the above code does is that we will keep looping for user input, where the time is expected to be in `HH:MM` format.  Note that I **did not** perform error checking, so it is expected that `HH` is between 0-23 while `MM` is between 0-59.  You keep putting in numbers by pushing in <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd> for each entry.  It parses this as a string, splits the string up at the `:` character, and converts each part before and after the `:` character into a number.  We then get the current time when each hour and minute was recorded using the `clock` command.  This is in a 6 element vector where the year, the month, the day, the hour, the minute and the second are recorded.  We simply replace the hour and minute with what we read in from the user, and zero the seconds.  We **finally** use this vector and append this to a `dateNumArray` variable where each time the user writes in a time, we will append a `datenum` number into this array.

When you call this, here is an example scenario:

```
Enter a time: 8:30
Enter a time: 8:45
Enter a time: 8:00
Enter a time:
```

Here's the example output from above:

```
format bank %// Show whole numbers and little precision
dateNumArray
format %// Reset format

dateNumArray =

 735778.35     735778.36     735778.33
```

Comment: M getting this error.
Undefined function 'strsplit' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: That's weird... `strsplit` is a **native** MATLAB function, but this is only supported from 2012 and onwards. Use this instead: `regexp(timestr,':','split');`

Comment: yeah I got the source of the error. My matlab version doesn't have that 'strsplit' function.

Comment: new error.     Index exceeds matrix dimensions.        Error in userInput (line 16)          timeRead(4:6) = [str2num(splitStr{1}) str2num(splitStr{2}) 0];

Comment: @Necromancer - the `regexp` expression should work. I just checked it.  Please use the modified code I wrote above.  I don't think you're using it properly.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your patience rayryeng! :)